# Find unique triplets

Tags: arrays, function, triplet

In my function I have to find all unique triplets to given numbers K from given array. It finds all triplets but many of them are there twice or more like `1 1 5` is same as `1 5 1` or `5 1 1` and etc.

Can somebody help me with this?

```
int triplet(int *array, int size, int K) {
  int i, j, k;
  int found = 0; /* triplets whose sum is equal to K */
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {    
      for (k = 0; k < size; k++) {
        if(array[i] + array[j] + array[k] == K) {
          printf("Triplet Found : %d, %d, %d\n", array[i], array[j], array[k]);
          found++;
        }           
      }
    }
  }
  return found;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not repeat already processed combinations; a possible solution would be to start each for cycle from de previous ID + 1, like so:

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
 for (j = i+1; j < size; j++) {    
  for (k = j+1; k < size; k++) {
    if(array[i] + array[j] + array[k] == K) {
      printf("Triplet Found : %d, %d, %d\n", array[i], array[j], array[k]);
      found++;
    }           
  }
}
```

setting `j = i + 1;` you prevent same-element triplets!

Comment: Using `id + 1` would not work for the example provided by the OP (1 1 5)

Comment: I think that it was an output example, not an input, and it would work:

Comment: array[0] + array[1] + array[2] == K

Answer (score 0):

To exclude combinations you could try the following change:

```
int triplet(int *array, int size, int K) {
  int i, j, k;
  int found = 0; /* triplets whose sum is equal to K */
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (j = i; j < size; j++) {    
      for (k = j; k < size; k++) {
        if(array[i] + array[j] + array[k] == K) {
          printf("Triplet Found : %d, %d, %d\n", array[i], array[j], array[k]);
          found++;
        }           
      }
    }
  }
  return found;
}
```

Notice the `j = i` and `k = j` statements in the `for loop` declarations. This way you will skip the possible duplicates for your case and yet cover all variations of the `i`, `j` and `k` variables.